# Vagrant - default: SSH auth method: private key Timeout

Tags: networking, ssh, windows-7, vagrant, vagrantfile

Having real hard time solving this one:

I'm trying to 'vagrant up' and everything seems ok until I reach a point:

```
==> default: The cookbook path 'C:/home/webs/cookbooks' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8081 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

## Configurations:

```
Vagrant 1.8.7
```

## plugins:

```
vagrant-berkshelf (5.1.1)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.5)
vagrant-share (1.1.6, system)
vagrant-triggers (0.5.3)
vagrant-vsphere (1.12.0)
```

## using:

```
Oracle Virtual Box v5.1.8
Chef v1.1.16
Windows-7
```

What I tried so far:

1. check if Virtualization is enabled.
2. remove the following folders: [.vagrant.d, .VirtualBox] [enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJhJb.png) and install all plugins again.
3. run with gui set to true, and I dont see any .ssh folder inside.
4. Turned off the firewall.

I Have other computers that have the same versions and run just fine. So I can compare. but I have no more clues how to continue from here...

Comment: its weird you dont have a `.ssh` folder in your VM - you should have the folder and an authorized_keys file. sometimes there's error with permission but vagrant should push the file

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: a program named: Web Companion Lavasoft was blocking the creation of ssh communication, I removed it and it worked.